# Liferay Web content display, disable default permissions for Guest/Site member

Tags: liferay, webcontent

I've previously added filters to  JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl Class before calling addArticleResources() method and setting the addGuestPermissions boolean to false to disable default permissions for Guest/Site member roles on WEB CONTENT.

The change reflects on control pannel--> Web content, but not on WEB CONTENT DISPLAY PORTLET.

What needs to be done to disable default gues/site member permissions on **Web content display**

liferay version: 6.1.2

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have an *article* which does not have guest view permission. When you add it to a Web Content Display *Portlet*, the portlet's permissions are unchanged?

In case this describes your situation: Note that this is completely expected: The *portlet* is configured to show *any article*. When the portlet is "protected", this has nothing to say for the article. A read-protected article on the other hand would leave an empty portlet, e.g. the article would not be shown, despite the *portlet's* permission.

If this does not describe your situation, please describe with more detail

Comment: You were right. How can I make the WEB CONTENT DISPLAY permissions reflect the web content permissions. Even when I create a new web content through web content display portlet, it shows having default guest permissions, but when I check the permissions of the same web content through control panel, it doesn't have guest permissions.